# Converting .bin to image coefficients and creating binary image using MATLAB and C

Tags: c, image, matlab, image-processing

I'm working on a homework assignment and we were given a .bin file that contained the data for a gray scale image. The objective here is to write C code that will convert this from a gray scale to a binary image. First thing was to open the greyscale image in MATLAB which I managed to do via:

```
A = fread(file, 256*256, 'uint8=>uint8');
A = reshape(A, 256, 256).';
imshow(A);
```

Great. I have my image coefficients which I split into 4 arrays and stuffed into C header files. I had to do it this way because the micro controller we're using for this class - the MSP430 - can't handle them all at once. I imported the first header file, set up my variables, and here is where all the heavy lifting is done:

```
for (i = 0; i == 16384; i++){
    if (suzi[i] >= 95){ //95 is given threshhold
        temp = 0b0000000;
    }
    else{
        temp = 0b00000001 << shiftby; //will right shift by 7, then 6, then 5 until 0 and then wrap back to 7
    }

    current = previous | temp; //updates the 8 bit data with the latest bit
    if(shiftby > 0){
        shiftby--; //decrements shifts until 0
    }
    else{
        shiftby = 7; //wraps back to 7
        suziarr[arrayindex] &= 0b00000000; //makes sure this value is 8 0s
        suziarr[arrayindex] |= current; //sets bits to match current 8 bit value
        current = 0b00000000;
        arrayindex++; //this is why the array will be 1/8 the size
    }

    previous = current; //update state

}
```

The temp, suzi, suziarr, previous, and current variables are declared as type unsigned char. suzi is also a const and is one of the arrays I stuffed into header files. suzi is set to length 13684 and suziarr is set to length 2048. For whatever reason, I get the exact same numbers no matter which of the 4 sets of data I use, so something is wrong here. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The loop

```
for (i = 0; i == 16384; i++)
```

will not iterate. It should be

```
for (i = 0; i < 16384; i++)
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that! Thanks! Okay so I have coefficients that make sense, but when I import them to MATLAB using the same commands as before, I get a column vector of size 31891x1 of type uint8. I'm looking for a column vector of the same type, but of size 65536x1 as I need to reshape this into a 256x256 image. Any thoughts?

Comment: Tried fscanf instead of fread and got a 8192x1 column vector of type double. If I could figure out a way to stretch this out to its 1s and 0s and get a 8192x8 vector, I'd be golden.

Comment: Is that a different question? You have not shown any of that.

Comment: Whoops. Forgot the MATLAB half of this. The .bin file, once imported, comes in as a column vector of size 65536x1 and type uint8. I can reshape that to get the 256x256 image. I saved my suziarr to a .dat file and imported it into MATLAB to try and get another 65536x1 array or at least something that can be reshaped into a 256x256 matrix so that I can generate the binary image I need.